# Had had confusion

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

1.Last year I had had the idea to buy a new television, but now I'm not sure I want to.

2 Last year I had  the idea to buy a new television, but now I'm not sure I want to

Both of these sentences saying that last year I wanted to but a new television, but not sure about this year. Then what is the basic difference between these two? I'm confused.

Comment: is this british english, american english, or australian english?

Comment: @Yay British maybe

Comment: It's the difference between past-perfect and simple past. Please show some research and [post on ELL.SE.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Sayan, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! This particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange instead.  In addition, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is less strict.

Comment: This may help you: *had had* is like *past past*, when something happened even before something in the past happened. Your sentence has no need for the rare-but correct construction. Your example has only one past item, so you don't need to past-past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wonder the difference between the "simple past" and the "past perfect"

I guess you already know the simple past so let me explain the past perfect briefly.

A event happened and B event happened later. A is faster than B.

In this case, you can describe A event using had+pp. Let me give you an example.

"When I went to the party(B), it had already finished(A)."

Your example ("though" was added to your original sentence to understand better):

1. "Though last year I had had the idea to buy a new television, but I'm not sure now." (O)
2. "Though last year I had the idea to buy a new television, but I'm not sure now." (O)

There is almost no difference but the only difference is "1" shows a very very little bit stronger determination than "2" because **had+pp** means "past **PERFECT**" - the past perfect implies something was done perfectly in the past, in your case, you had the idea to buy a new TV as a perfect one(=idea) in the past though it is not now. (perfect means "something **finished** until then or at that time")

For the case "2" which is a **SIMPLE** past, it means just a "past", NOT PERFECT.
You simply thought that you would buy a new television, but it is not now.

But remember that "1" and "2" have almost no difference there.